# Creating Paypal custom event registration forms

Tags: paypal

I have a very specific registration form that I need to build that collects an event attendees information and then sends that info plus payment to a Paypal business account. My client has given me the breakdown of how he wants the form to work and it goes something like this:

> Registration Options: A) Single person/participant: cost $150.00 B)
>   Family group/ 2 or more participants: $300 total for the first two
>   each additional is $75. C) School group: For every six participants
>   paid at $150 each the 7th will be free
>
> Select registration package: Number of Participants: Total cost for
>   participation:

This seems like a tough task even with Paypal's button building feature.
Can anyone offer any suggestions on how I might tackle this form? Possibly through a php form that will auto total based on fields filled in by the attendee?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways that you can do this.  You could use some JavaScript or PHP to collect the data and perform the calculations.  There are a few example of some basic scripts collecting data and performing calculations [here](http://ccaples.com/index.php/basic-scripts/examples-i/event-rsvp) that may help, or give you an idea of how you would go about doing this.  The examples are free to use as is.  There are several others that may help as well, under the basic scripts menu.  Some are Java Script, others are in PHP.  You can just right click the page and view the code for the JavaScript, and for the ones that are in PHP, there should be a link for the PHP code.